# Fit table a bit outside of text margins

Tags: tables, margins

Following my post here, how could I use the command:

```
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{...}
```

to place a table a bit outside of the text margins?

EDIT:

At the moment this works fine for me. My only problem is that the height changes correspondingly which is something that I do not want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\spacing{1.5}
% \raggedright

\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1.3\textwidth,center}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Fuels}} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{Numbes}} \\
            \hline
            \ttfamily XXXXXXXXXX & \ttfamily XXX \\
            \ttfamily XXXXXXXXXX & \ttfamily XXX \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{Selected fuels}
    \label{tab:SelectedFuels}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would only resize text as a last resort. It can be very distracting to have sections of the document using arbitrarily changing font sizes just to make things fit. You can make the table extend beyond the margins, or adjust the inter-column spaces, or use specific design size such as `\small` or `\footnotesize` any of which might be preferable to scaling.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right. Its a bit ugly to use arbitrarily font sizes. But, what else can I do? Can you give me further instructions?

Comment: Well I gave some examples in the previous comment. Hard to say any more without any indication of the input table or what size you are trying to fit it to.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: That's a narrow table, I'd just use `\centering\begin{tabular}...` Do you really want to use a massive font to make it wider or have a massive gap between the columns just so they reach the edge?

Comment: I just want all the tables have the same width but not the same height, and of course not such huge fonts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some possibilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3in,right=3in,showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\noindent\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   some thing & some thing & some thing & some thing & some thing \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.2\textwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   some thing & some thing & some thing & some thing & some thing \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   some thing & some thing & some thing & some thing & some thing \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\resizebox{1.2\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   some thing & some thing & some thing & some thing & some thing \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}%
}%
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Given that I would like to set a specific width for each table, \usepackage{adjustbox} seems as the best choice, right? However, I get the following error when loading the package \usepackage{adjustbox}: ! LaTeX Error: File `trimclip.sty' not found.

Comment: @Hurish: Just changed the original post. The problem is that the height changes correspondingly which is something that I do not want.

Comment: @Hurish: The MWE is up. Please take a look if you don't mind.

Comment: @eualin: When you use `\resizebox` the hieght as well as width get resized. Here fonts are also resized and correspondingly the baseline skip etc. If you increase only the width, the fonts get skewed and look ugly. This solution is good only if you have a wide table that won't fit inside the margin. By the way what are you after if your table is not that wide?. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @eualin: You can control the height also by putting `height=4cm,` as in `\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.3\textwidth,height=4cm,center}`. But I can't stand to see the results.

Comment: Well, I first posted this question for wide tables only. It works fine for them. But then I though it would be a good idea if every table had the same width (but not the same height). So I applied it to all tables. But some of the tables are ugly now. In other words, what I am trying to do now is make all these tables have a unified appearance. Any ideas?

Comment: @eualin: May be you can try to hack the `tabularx`. This can be a potential candidate for a new question (follow-up question). You may link this question for reference.

Answer (score 4):

Based on discussion in comments, I think you want something like this with two tables set to the same width:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}



\usepackage[margin=1.3in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}



\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{table}[hpt]
\centering
        \begin{tabular*}{.7\textwidth}{|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll@{}|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Fuels}} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{Numbes}} \\
            \hline
            \ttfamily XXXXXXXXXX & \ttfamily XXX \\
            \ttfamily XXXXXXXXXX & \ttfamily XXX \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular*}

    \caption{Selected fuels}
    \label{tab:SelectedFuels}
\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{table}[hpt]
\centering
        \begin{tabular*}{.7\textwidth}{|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll@{}|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{Fuels}} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\head{Numbes}} \\
            \hline
            \ttfamily XXXXXXX & \ttfamily XXX \\
            \ttfamily XXXXXXX & \ttfamily XXXYYYY \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular*}

    \caption{Selected fuels2}
    \label{tab:SelectedFuels2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note I changed `[H]` to `[hpt]` as I can say with some authority (being the person who first implemented it) that `[H]` is usually a bad choice. also I removed the `\spacing` command as that generates an error at the end of document as it starts a group but doesn't close it. I think it is intended to be used as an environment `\begin{spacing}..\end{spacing}` but didn't check the `setspace` documentation.